# Semilinear Poisson PDE - proving a (hopefully) simple inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

This is from page 557 of PDE Evans, 2nd edition. My question is at the bottom of this post, but for now, here is some context for my question:

> **LEMMA 2** (Boundary estimates)**.** Let $u \in C^2(\bar{U})$ satisfy $\text{(2)}$, $\text{(3)}$. Then for each point $x^0 \in \partial U \cap \{x_n > 0\}$, either $$u_{x_n}(x^0) < 0 \tag{7}$$ or else $$u_{x_n}(x^0)=0, \, u_{x_n x_n}(x^0)>0. \tag{8}$$ In either case, $u$ is strictly decreasing as a function of $x_n$ near $x^0$.

For reference, here are $\text{(2)}$ and $\text{(3)}$ from the book:

> In this subsection we take $U = B^0(0,1)$ to be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and investigate this boundary-value problem for a semilinear Poisson PDE: $$\begin{cases}-\Delta u = f(u) & \text{in }U \\ \quad \, \, \,  u=0 & \text{on }\partial U. \end{cases} \tag{2}$$  We are interested in *positive solutions*: $$u > 0 \quad \text{in }U \tag{3}$$ and will assume $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous but otherwise arbitrary.

Now, here is a fragment of the proof to Lemma 2:

> **Proof.** 1. Fix any point $x^0 \in \partial U \cap\{x_n > 0\}$ and let $\nu = \mathbf{\nu}(x^0)=\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_n)$ denote the outer unit normal to $\partial U$ at $x^0$. Note $\nu_n > 0$.
>
> 2. We first claim $$u_{x_n}(x^0)<0,$$ provided $$f(0) \ge 0. \tag{9}$$ Indeed \begin{align}0=-\Delta u -f(u) &=-\Delta u-f(u)+f(0)-f(0) \\ &\le -\Delta u + cu, \end{align} for $c(x) := -\int_0^1 f'(su(x)) \, ds$.

**My question:**
How does one obtain this inequality $0 \le -\Delta u + cu$? Here is what I did so far (in attempting to add more details):
\begin{align}
0 &= -\Delta u - f(u) \\
&= -\Delta u - f(0) - (f(u)-f(0)) \\
&= -\Delta u - f(0) + c \\
&\le -\Delta u - f(0) + cu \qquad (u \ge 0  \text{ in $U$ by (3)}) \\
&\le -\Delta u + 0 + cu \\
&= -\Delta u + cu
\end{align}
I'm not sure about my first inequality in which I tried to justify using $u \ge 0$. That probably does not conclude the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $f(u(x))-f(0)$ is equal to $-cu(x)$, not to $-c$. Indeed,
$$-cu(x) = u(x)\int_0^1 f'(su(x)) \, ds = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds}
\left(f(su(x))\right) \, ds = f(u(x))-f(0)$$
where the second equality is the chain rule.

(Keep in mind that in general, $f'(2x)$ means $f'$ evaluated at $2x$, not the derivative of $f(2x)$.)

So, 
$$-\Delta u-f(u)+f(0)-f(0) \le -\Delta u-f(u)+f(0) = -\Delta u+cu$$

---

Comment: Additionally, on page 559, the author writes $w(x):= u(x_{\lambda_0})-u(x)$ and then writes $$-\Delta w=f(u(x_{\lambda_0}))-f(u(x))=-cw,$$ employing similar reasoning for the last equality. To show this, I employed your reasoning here by saying $$-cw = \left[\int_0^1 f'(su(x_{\lambda_0})+(1-s)u(x)) \, ds \right](u(x_{\lambda_0})-u(x))=\int_0^1 \frac d{ds} f(su(x_{\lambda_0})+(1-s)u(x)) \, ds=f(u(x_{\lambda_0}))-f(u(x)).$$ Does this sound right?

Comment: And it is for $c(x) := -\int_0^1 f'(su(x_{\lambda_0})+(1-s)u(x)) \, ds$, as also written on page 559.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.